# When a user expects a feature but you don't offer it, should you alert them to this fact?

Tags: user-expectation, search, notification

Yesterday I was writing an article on lesserwrong.com. I am used to writing on [Medium](https://medium.com/). On Medium, you can embed videos into your article. On lesserwrong.com, you can't. I was expecting it to be possible on lesserwrong.com, so I took a while trying to figure out whether or not it was possible and ended up having to contact support. I would have rather just been notified up front something along the lines of: "You may be looking to embed a video. We don't offer that feature right now."

Today I was on Betterment. My external accounts last synced three days ago. I want them to sync right now. I don't see a way to manually sync them. I spent about 5 minutes looking around to see if it is possible. It seems that it isn't. I would have rather just been notified up front something along the lines of: "You may be looking to manually sync your external accounts. We don't offer that feature."

In general, is it a good idea to notify users that a feature they're probably looking for doesn't exist?

Comment: I don’t think so, mainly because it’s impossible to determine what a user might expect feature wise. One way to counter this issue (if statistics show you have this problem) is to tackle your on boarding and show users what they can do. Then it’s more obvious what the app can do (and therefore what not).

Comment: The set of freatures any application does not implement is infinite - best not guess here.  Perhaps provide a questionnaire and ask if there is any feature that they would find useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to add a feature upon general request or to match a competitor, there is always the option to add a place holder.

For exemple, in an **`insert`** menu, where video is not yet supported,

`Image
Link
(Coming soon! Video)`